# center img in div with several elements

Tags: javascript, css

this is my div:

```
        <div>
            <img src="picture.png" class="picture"/>
            <span class="done-button">Done</span>
        </div>
```

I want the image to be in the center of the screen and the done button close to the right (not all the way, small padding).
Can anyone help?
My main problem is centering the image in the middle of the screen when there is another element in the same div.

BTW no size is fixed...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help you!

```css
#image-wrapper{
  text-align: center
}
.done-button{
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200" class="picture" />
  <span class="done-button">Done</span>
</div>
```